# SQL Update column with $var data

Tags: php, mysql

```
$newCity = $_POST['city'];

$set = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET city = '$newCity' WHERE username = '$theUser'");
```

I'm trying to update `mySql` column through `UPDATE` using a value of a variable.
But when I check the value, it updates, but once I refresh the execute, it changes the value to NULL

Edit: `$theUser = a working session username`

Comment: What do you mean refresh the execute? Are you re-submiting the form?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
if(isset($_POST['city'])){
 $newCity = $_POST['city'];
 $set = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET city = '$newCity' WHERE username = '$theUser'");
}
```

Also please try to filter your user input before passing it to query.

Comment: Passing variable from `$_POST` directly into query is easy way how to be SQL injected... Don't forget to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['city'])){
   $newCity = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['city']);
   $theUser = mysqli_real_escape_string($userUser); // assuming you haven't escaped it already.
   $query = "UPDATE users SET city = '$newCity' WHERE username = '$theUser'";
   $set = mysqli_query($con, $query);
}
```